# TableView and Spinner in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, spinner, tablecell

I'm able to set in a table cell a spinner.

[image]

But the problem is that i'm not able to get this value when i use getSelectionModel().

There is some way to do this?

The code that i'm currently using is this:

```
 QuantitaCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Strumento, Integer>("Quantita_Disp"));

 QuantitaCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Strumento,Integer>,TableCell<Strumento,Integer>>(){        
        @Override
        public TableCell<Strumento, Integer> call(TableColumn<Strumento, Integer> param) {                
            TableCell<Strumento, Integer> cell = new TableCell<Strumento, Integer>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                    if(item!=null){
                       Spinner<Integer> quantita = new Spinner<Integer>(0, item, 1);     
                       quantita.valueProperty().addListener(
                               (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                                    System.out.println("New value: "+item);

                                }
                       );
                       setGraphic(quantita);
                    } 
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create the `Spinner` and set the value, however you never write the value back to your items. To do this

a) your item class needs to contain the max value and the current value for the spinner (or only the current value, if the max is the same for every item)
b) The `ObservableValue` for a column needs to contain data for both the max and the current value.

The following sample simply uses the table item itself as value for the column:

```
public static class Item {

    private final IntegerProperty itemCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty itemMaxCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(getItemCount());
    }

    public Item(int disp, int max) {
        this.itemCount.setValue(disp);
        this.itemMaxCount.setValue(max);
    }

    public final int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemCount.get();
    }

    public final void setItemCount(int value) {
        this.itemCount.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty itemCountProperty() {
        return this.itemCount;
    }

    public final int getItemMaxCount() {
        return this.itemMaxCount.get();
    }

    public final void setItemMaxCount(int value) {
        this.itemMaxCount.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty itemMaxCountProperty() {
        return this.itemMaxCount;
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> tv = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Item(1, 10),
            new Item(0, 9),
            new Item(1, 8),
            new Item(0, 7),
            new Item(1, 42),
            new Item(0, 4),
            new Item(1, 2),
            new Item(0, 99),
            new Item(1, 77),
            new Item(0, 44),
            new Item(1, 11),
            new Item(0, 2),
            new Item(1, 2),
            new Item(0, 3),
            new Item(1, 5),
            new Item(0, 6)
    ));

    TableColumn<Item, Item> countColumn = new TableColumn<>("count");
    countColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> cd.getValue()));

    countColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Item, Item>, TableCell<Item, Item>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Item, Item> call(TableColumn<Item, Item> param) {
            TableCell<Item, Item> cell = new TableCell<Item, Item>() {

                private final Spinner<Integer> count;

                private final SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory;
                private final ChangeListener<Number> valueChangeListener;

                {
                    valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 0);
                    count = new Spinner<>(valueFactory);
                    count.setVisible(false);
                    setGraphic(count);
                    valueChangeListener = (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
                        valueFactory.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                    };
                    count.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        if (getItem() != null) {
                            // write new value to table item
                            getItem().setItemCount(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {

                    // unbind old values
                    valueFactory.maxProperty().unbind();
                    if (getItem() != null) {
                        getItem().itemCountProperty().removeListener(valueChangeListener);
                    }

                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    // update according to new item
                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        count.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        valueFactory.maxProperty().bind(item.itemMaxCountProperty());
                        valueFactory.setValue(item.getItemCount());
                        item.itemCountProperty().addListener(valueChangeListener);
                        count.setVisible(true);
                    }

                }
            };

            return cell;
        }
    });

    tv.getColumns().add(countColumn);

    Button btn = new Button("Print");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println(tv.getItems());
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, tv, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative code instead of using updateItem() and setGraphic() function

```
TableColumn<Strumento, Spinner> SpinnerCol = new TableColumn<Strumento, Spinner>("Quantity");

        SpinnerCol.setMinWidth(500);
        SpinnerCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Strumento, Spinner>, ObservableValue<Spinner>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Spinner> call(
                    TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Strumento, Spinner> arg0) {
                Strumento strumentoObject = arg0.getValue();

                Spinner<Integer> quantita = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 10, 1);
                quantita.valueProperty().addListener(
                        (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                            System.out.println("New value: " + newValue);

                             strumentoObject.setSpinnerValue(newValue);



                        }
                );

                return new SimpleObjectProperty<Spinner>(quantita);

            }

        });
        table.getColumns().add(SpinnerCol);
```

**EDITED**

Though this solution quickly solves your problem,I strongly suggest you to follow [fabian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37813476/4254056) solution as recommended by experts in below comments.

Comment: This results in really unhealthy coupling between model and view... Furthermore `Node`s are quite huge objects and storing them in the table item class results in a significant increase in memory used, which depending on the number of items can become a issue... (Number of properties required to store the actual data: 2; number of properties of `Spinner`: >100)

Comment: I agree with @fabian - this is not a recommended solution. Any time you are using `Node` subclasses (such as `Spinner`) as a data type (i.e. the type of the column: `TableColumn<Strumento, Spinner>`) it is a sign your design is wrong.